# Does Rails' #link_to only accept one parameter in its block when used outside of ERB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

When I did this in ERB, it works as expected, giving me an `a` tag that wraps around an image and some text

```
<%= link_to(...) do %>
  <img src="..." />
  text
<% end %>
```

But when I tried to put this in a method, the `a` tag only wraps the last argument, which in this case, is the text.

```
  def build_link
    link_to(...) do
      image_tag(...)
      text
    end
  end
```

Looking at the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), they only gave an example of using `link_to` in ERB, so is it smart to assume that using it in a method doesn't work as well and can't accept two parameters?

Comment: I think this expected behavior, as that's how the block is read. You should be able to use `concat` to combine both the `image_tag` and `text` in your helper, though. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up to my comment:

The reason is behavior happens is because of how Ruby handles blocks, and how Rails handles the output for ActionController.

The trick here is to use handy-dandy `concat`.

```
def build_link
  link_to("#") do
    concat image_tag("http://placehold.it/300x300")
    concat "hello world"
  end
end
```

Pretend the block you pass to `link_to` is just another method, and it gets returned some object/value. In this case, your `text` object gets returned.

But because you want to output both `image_tag` and `text`, you need to pass that together to the output.